# Setting the value of a treemap within a treemap?

Tags: java, treemap

Please bear with me, I've been searching online all morning trying to find the proper syntax for a slight problem that's occurring. How would you set a treemap within a treemap?

The instance variable for the map is:

```
    private final TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,Double>> matrix;

/**
 * Change the value at a given position.
 * If the position is not in the matrix (i.e., i is not between 0 and rows-1
 * and j is not between 0 and cols-1), then don't change anything.
 *
 * @param i The row.
 * @param j The column.
 * @param v The new value.
 */
public void set(int i, int j, double v) {
    if (matrix.containsKey(i) && matrix.containsValue(j) == true) {
        matrix.remove(j); // Is this needed?
        matrix.put(i<j,v>); // ERROR: not right syntax for this 
    }
} // end of set method
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?,

```
matrix.get(i).put(j, v);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private final TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,Double>> matrix;
```

You can not assign a value to an instance which is declared as final, other than, at the statement you are declaring it:

```
public final TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,Double>> matrix  = new TreeMap<>();
```

Then you should be able to `put`, `get` `TreeMap` from the `matrix` as usual:

```
matrix.put(1, new TreeMap<Integer, Double>());
matrix.get(1).put(1, 1.23);
```